# How to disable any error script pop up in ASP.NET Project

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, internet-explorer

I have build ASP.NET Project but worried to have issue in javascript. How to disable error script in ASP.NET, 'Script Error' pop up that javascript error or issue like this example.

[image: er.jpg]

I have been disable 'debug mode=false' in the webconfig and then disable compile warning in Visual Studio before published, or disable debug in IE, but is nothing. 
What ever the error script, Any code (C#/VB.net) for prevent this message?

Note : I must using IE Browser.

Thank you,

Comment: Don't you think it'd be better to fix the error instead of hiding it?

Comment: I believe in this case, I have priority to hiding it while resolve the issue. Also, I worried if sometimes "error script" pop up is occured in another issue script.

Comment: Come on, have a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28293960/datetimepicker-component-not-in-right-place). The should be easily fixable.

Comment: Okay assumed this case is solved like example above. But there a way to prevent the script pop up message, I worried if another script error occured because I must use Internet Explorer, you know IE has many compability issue especially Old IE (10).

Answer (score 0):

I suggest wrapping the problematic javascript code in a     try {} catch {} block. Then you can deal with the error instead of making a pop up.